# SQLAlchemy automatically converts str to unicode on commit

Tags: python, unicode, sqlalchemy

When inserting an object into a database with SQLAlchemy, all it's properties that correspond to String() columns are automatically transformed from <type 'str'> to <type 'unicode'>. Is there a way to prevent this behavior?

Here is the code:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Table, Column, Integer, String, MetaData
from sqlalchemy.orm import mapper, sessionmaker

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=False)
metadata = MetaData()

table = Table('projects', metadata,
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column('name', String(50))
)

class Project(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

mapper(Project, table)
metadata.create_all(engine)

session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)()

project = Project("Lorem ipsum")

print(type(project.name))

session.add(project)
session.commit()

print(type(project.name))
```

And here is the output:

```
<type 'str'>
<type 'unicode'>
```

I know I should probably just work with unicode, but this would involve digging through some third-party code and I don't have the Python skills for that yet :)

Comment: Here's two ugly hacks: either use Binary instead of String or `engine.connect().connection.connection.text_factory = str`

Comment: Thank you very much, I would have accepted this solution if you would have posted an answer :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Actually, there is a way to do that. Just execute this line of code after creating engine:

engine.raw_connection().connection.text_factory = str

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, you are out of luck and this does not seem to work with `sqlite`. A quote from [SQLAlchemy 0.6.2 Documentation - SQLite - Unicode](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/reference/dialects/sqlite.html#unicode):

> In contrast to SQLAlchemy’s active
>   handling of date and time types for
>   pysqlite, pysqlite’s default behavior
>   regarding Unicode is that all strings
>   are returned as Python unicode objects
>   in all cases. So even if the Unicode 
>   type is not used, you will still
>   always receive unicode data back from
>   a result set. It is strongly
>   recommended that you do use the
>   Unicode  type to represent strings,
>   since it will raise a warning if a
>   non-unicode Python string is passed
>   from the user application. Mixing the
>   usage of non-unicode objects with
>   returned unicode objects can quickly
>   create confusion, particularly when
>   using the ORM as internal data is not
>   always represented by an actual
>   database result string.

Comment: Ahh, so I will only have this problem with SQLite, good to know. I do plan on using unicode in the future :)

Comment: well, it is now obvious from zifot's answer that this really depends on the underlying driver; but sqlite is the only one mentioned in SA documentation